# Map of function pointers. Does the function being pointed to have to be static?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, static, function-pointers

I've only just yesterday figured out function pointers, and I am implementing a console/command system in a game engine.

I figured using a map with a string key and function pointer value would eliminate the need for a huge list of if statements when choosing what to do when running the commands.

I'm getting this error:

```
argument of type
    "void (Game::*)(std::string prop, std::string param)"
is incompatible with parameter of type
    "void (*)(std::string prop, std::string param)"
```

Now I think I know what this means. I could use a static function to get round this, but I want to be able to reference a method of a specific instance of `Game`.

However the map of function pointers must be able to point to any function with return void and 2 string parameters.

Firstly is this possible?

If not, is it somehow possible to modify instance variables through a static member function? I don't have high hopes for this.

Any help is appreciated as always.

Comment: Your two requirements explicitly conflict. "*I want to be able to reference a method of a specific instance of Game.*" That means the function must take a pointer or reference to an instance of `Game`. "*the map of function pointers must be able to point to any function with return void and 2 string parameters.*" That means the map must hold functions that don't take a pointer or reference to an instance of `Game`.

Comment: There's no conflict here. Type erasure and lambdas easily produce the solution.

Comment: by that I meant not just `("void (Game::*)(std::string prop, std::string param)")` or `("void (Renderer*)(std::string prop, std::string param)")` but **ANY** type of function pointer with signature "void function(string,string)". Sorry if I didn't explain enough.

Comment: @Finlaybob: But in that case, you can't reference a method of a specific instance of `Game`, which was one of your requirements.

Comment: @David: Of course he can. Using type erasure. And lambdas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function pointers are the suck. Don't ever use them unless you're absolutely forced to. Instead, prefer `std::function<void(std::string, std::string)>` and `std::bind`/lambdas. Unlike function pointers, these can work with any function object, including a bound member function.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()>> command_map;
Game game;
Help helper;
command_map["quit"] = [] { exit(); };
command_map["play"] = [&] { game.play(); };
command_map["help"] = [&] { helper.help(); };
```

Comment: That sound more like what I need, thanks. However I've never come across this before. I'll commence an assault on Google, any helpful links?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Check out [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx) link.

Comment: I.. don't really know :( I'm using VS2010. If that helps?

Comment: It does. The link I gave you is for VS2010, specifically, and this code is definitely valid. Lambdas are part of what's called C++11 (older references name it C++0x), which is a new version of the C++ language. VS2010 supports a few features from that package, and these classes and lambdas are some of them. Why don't you come to the [C++ chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec)?

Comment: Thanks again! I heard some references to C++0x and C++11 a while ago and actually thought they were different things :|

Answer (score 1):

You can put an object and a function pointer in the map.  Then call a static version of the function which just calls the real version of the function on the object passed in.  You can repeat this for as many functions in `Game` as you like.

```
class Game
{
    void yourFunc1(std::string prop, std::string param)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    void yourFunc1_static(Game* g, std::string prop, std::string param)
    {
        g->yourFunc1( prop, param );
    }
};

struct MapEntry
{
    Game* game;
    void (*func)(std::string prop, std::string param);
};

std::map<key_type, MapEntry> _map;
...
_map[key].func( game, "prop", "param" );
```

Comment: Gotta downvote you for your non-solution. He needs a generic function object, not this.

Comment: Sorry If I haven't explained it correctly, the `MapEntry` in your example cannot have a pointer to a Game object. The functions will be pointing to various different things, Game was just an example. It's not a problem to get a pointer to the instance I want, its just the map will not be able to hold a function pointer to a `void (*)(Game*,string,string)` type but also a `void(*)(Renderer*,string,string)` will it?